# JBPM gwt-console-server user management

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss, jbpm

I want to integrate the jbpm 5.4 into my application which is based on Spring MVC 3. This integration performed using REST API. I have already user table which stores the username and password in the table. This is table is the part of my user management module.

Issue is that can I use my user table as users in gwt-console-server (REST API) in jbpm? Because jbpm uses Java property file for user management.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the new console ng that we are building? It is much easier to integrate and to extend. Check it out from GitHub : GitHub.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-console-ng/

Answer (score 0):

jBPM is using JAAS for authentication, which by default stores users / groups into properties files.  But you can reconfigure your security domain to use for example a database or LDAP as backend as well.